# How do you tell NHibernate to ignore persisting a child object

Tags: nhibernate

How do you tell NHibernate to ignore persisting a child object? I have my my mapping set up so a Person has an address so when I attempt to persist Person without an address or with a new address then gives a flushing error. Now I know I can Cascade, but is it possible to tell NHibnerate not to worry about the address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Not map the address at all
- Cascade the address
- Save the address manually

You can't selectively ignore some objects.